# How can I turn a UI panel on using gameObject.SetActive(true)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

apologies for the super-beginner question. I'm trying to create a market simulator in Unity C#, where you can buy/sell items using a preset amount of money.

I'm using an if/then statement, where if the user has insufficient funds but tries to buy something, a UI panel with an alert gets enabled using gameObject.SetActive(true). I know that the alert is being triggered because it says so in the console, but the UI panel fails to go active. However, when I use the same code to —disable— the UI panel with (gameObject.SetActive(false) it works perfectly fine.

```
public GameObject objectToError;
// the above line allows me to choose which object I'm disabling.

    public void
    BuyGE()
    {
        if (GE.Bank > GE.price)
        {
            GE.Amount++;
            GE.Bank -= (int)GE.price;
        }

// this part adds the item to your inventory, and removes the respective
// amount of cash from your bank.

        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("turn on that panel");
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
// if you don't have enough cash, this alert triggers a UI panel by making it active.
// This is where I have the problem.
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that you're referencing the wrong object. The line should be something as:

> objectToError.SetActive(true);

otherwise gameObject points to the gameobject that has the script, that will probably not be the one to enable in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be improved.

### New BuyGE function:

```
BuyGE()
{
    if (GE.Bank > GE.price)
    {
        GE.Amount++;
        GE.Bank -= (int)GE.price;
    }

    objectToError.SetActive(GE.Bank > GE.price);
}
```